# groupby with conditions pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to generate a summarized dataframe (using groupby). While I have done basic aggregations before, this one has more complex aggregation conditions. I have tried the web help but unable to work my waythrough.

sample data :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'indi_id': [1,1,1,2,2],
                   'co_id': [1,1,2,2,3],
                   'relationship': ['shareholder', 'signatory', 'shareholder', 'shareholder', 'director'],
                   'co_type': ['SP', 'SP', 'PT', 'PT', 'SP'],
                   'co_nw': [10,10,100,100,2],
                   'sh_perc': [100, np.nan, 3, 4, np.nan]})
```

What I need to do is generate a summary dataframe below (groupby: indi_id):

```
indi_id: 'groupby field' 
num_cos_assoc: 'nunique'(co_ID) - no problems here
num_companies_assoc_sh: nunique(co_ID) where relationship = 'shareholder'
num_SP_companies_assoc: nunique(co_ID) where co_type = 'SP'
total_nw_co_sh: sum(co_nw*sh_prec) where relationship = 'shareholder'
```

sample Outcome below:

```
Indi_ID num_cos_assoc   num_companies_assoc_sh  num_SP_companies_assoc  total_nw_co_sh
1       2               2                       1                       1300
2       2               1                       0                       400
```

Comment: sample outcome:
[1 2 2 1 13], [2 2 1 0 4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom function with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html), because [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) be design working with each column separately, so filtering by another columns is really problematic:

```
def f(x):
    a = x['co_id'].nunique()
    b = x.loc[x['relationship'] == 'shareholder', 'co_id'].nunique()
    c = x.loc[x['co_type'] == 'SP', 'co_id'].nunique()
    d = x.loc[x['relationship'] == 'shareholder', ['co_nw', 'sh_perc']]
    d = d['co_nw'].mul(d['sh_perc'], fill_value=1).sum()
    cols =['num_cos_assoc','num_companies_assoc_sh','num_SP_companies_assoc','total_nw_co_sh']
    return pd.Series([a,b,c,d], index=cols)

df1 = df.groupby('indi_id').apply(f).reset_index()
print (df1)
   indi_id  num_cos_assoc  num_companies_assoc_sh  num_SP_companies_assoc  \
0        1            2.0                     2.0                     1.0   
1        2            2.0                     1.0                     1.0   

   total_nw_co_sh  
0          1300.0  
1           400.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it without a custom function, though it really sums up to doing the same thing as jezrael's solution:

```
df.groupby('indi_id').apply(lambda x: pd.Series([
                   x.co_id.nunique(),
                   x.loc[x.relationship == 'shareholder'].co_id.nunique(),
                   x.loc[x.co_type == 'SP'].co_id.nunique(),
                   x.loc[x.relationship == 'shareholder'][['co_nw','sh_perc']].prod(axis = 1).sum()],
    index = ['num_cos_assoc','num_companies_assoc_sh','nump_SP_companies_assoc','total_nw_co_sh']))
```

And the corresponding output:

```
           num_cos_assoc num_companies_assoc_sh nump_SP_companies_assoc total_nw_co_sh
indi_id
1          2.0           2.0                     1.0                    1300.0 
2          2.0           1.0                     1.0                    400.0
```